# Flutter ClassNotFoundException (java.lang.RuntimeException) crash error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-play-services, bundle

Recently, I uploaded my Flutter app to Play Store.
My app crashed after installing and opening the app.
I've got several Crash Reports.
I did researched everywhere about this error and found nothing,
I even contacted Google Play's Support.

I am using Firebase Auth, cloud_firestore, google_sign_in... (check pubspec.yamll)

Help will be appreciated

Flutter Doctor:

```
Active code page: 1252
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[âˆš] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Active code page: 1252

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale he-IL)

[âˆš] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[âˆš] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[âˆš] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[âˆš] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: iusefully
description: Be more productive

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.0+1

module:
  androidX: true

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  google_sign_in: 4.5.1 
  firebase_auth: 0.16.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
  # cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  cloud_firestore: 0.13.6

  rxdart: 0.20.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  provider: ^4.0.4
  flutter_phoenix: "^0.1.0"
  animations: ^1.0.0+5
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - images/google.png
    - images/login.png
    - images/human1.png
    - images/onboarding0.png
    - images/onboarding1.png
    - images/onboarding2.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  fonts:
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
    - family: NotoSans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf

  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2.0+1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

// def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
// def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "CLASSIFIED"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (root)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' // 3.5.0
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

- I have keystore (.jks) as well. But I think the problem isn't there.
- I am using app bundles

Thanks in advance :)

Crash Log (using master channel):

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...                                                                                                                                                                                                D
Active code page: 1252
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Active code page: 1252
Active code page: 1252
Note: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        41.9s
âˆš Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                 2.6s
E/FlutterLoader( 6685): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterLoader( 6685): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tomeruby.iusefully-0JfExLxHhUqLUimkj6h-1Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tomeruby.iusefully-0JfExLxHhUqLUimkj6h-1Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:193)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:207)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:188)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:154)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:229)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:151)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:409)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tomeruby.iusefully-0JfExLxHhUqLUimkj6h-1Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tomeruby.iusefully-0JfExLxHhUqLUimkj6h-1Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:145)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:140)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
E/FlutterLoader( 6685):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Can you please past the whole crash logs? **Flutter ClassNotFoundException (java.lang.RuntimeException) crash error** It's just saying that you are having a runtime exception nothing more. Plus whenever you are publishing your app to Playstore, it's always a good practice to push your app to alpha or beta track to test your app before pushing it to production. I usually create .apk file release before publishing it to play store so that I can test it on real device as well :D

Comment: sure, check update.

Comment: Did you build a release .apk file and tested on real devices ?

Comment: yes, published to play store and it just crashed immediately on startup. Never happened before

Comment: I should mention that it is a differnet problem on Android 9 and Android 10, The error log is from Android 9 emulator.

Comment: I see I guess the problem is with the master channel. Why don't you try to run the app on stable ?

Comment: I ran it on stable before, but when I ran it on master... It showed the error logs.

Comment: I changed to master just today.

Comment: Are you testing something on master  ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that flutter suggest to build apps on the **stable channel**, so I thought you were testing your app on master channel

Comment: oh, I built the app on stable the whole time. I moved to master because I thought that the happened occurred after ``flutter upgrade`` so I tried ``flutter downgrade`` and it said to move to master channel

Comment: hehe **stable channel** is named stable because it is stable. If you are building a production-ready app then you should always go with stable. If you want to test some new features on Flutter then use the beta, dev, and master channels. For example, if you want to try flutter web then you should change your channel to beta because its still undergoing some changes and updates and not ready production.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215743/discussion-between-tomer-and-chinky-sight).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
}
```

fixed it.
Add the line to `app/build.gradle`

Comment: I generated an app.aab file using - flutter build appbundle. so then after I need to add

ndk {
    abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
}

it will work for .aab or I need to create APK with this command - flutter build apk

Comment: I think its working both aab and apk builds.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37566#issuecomment-647800555